# How to initialize a global matrix depending on data that is generated when begins the program?

Tags: java, exception

I am creating a program that has to hold many information one of this stores a matrix in which , the idea is to keep 0 or -1 depending if the item exists (0), in other case (-1). But when I'm trying to initialize this matrix in a method generates a nullPointerException.

I tried to fix it initializing the matrix like this:

```
public static int libros[][]= new int[arrayListLibros.size()][numeroMayor()];
```

but it generates another error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at Modelo.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Modelo.SistemaDeGestion.<clinit>(SistemaDeGestion.java:19)
... 1 more
```

I didn't find how to solve it

Here is the code:

```
    public void cargarMatrizLibros() throws Exception{
    int numeroMayor = numeroMayor();
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayListLibros.size(); j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < numeroMayor; k++){
            if( k < Integer.getInteger(arrayListLibros.get(j).getEjemplares())){
                libros[j][k] = 0;
            }
            else{
                libros[j][k] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static int numeroMayor(){
    int numeroMayor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayListLibros.size(); i++) {
        if(Integer.getInteger(arrayListLibros.get(i).getEjemplares()) > numeroMayor){
            numeroMayor = Integer.getInteger(arrayListLibros.get(i).getEjemplares());
        }
    }
    return numeroMayor;
}
```

arrayListLibros was initialized previously in the main method of the program:

```
SistemaDeGestion sistema = new SistemaDeGestion();
    try {
        sistema.cargarDatosEmpleados();
        sistema.cargarDatosUsuarios();
        sistema.cargarDatosLibros();
        sistema.cargarMatrizLibros();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

where sistema makes reference to a class created... And the code for cargarDatosLibros is here:

```
public void cargarDatosLibros() throws Exception {
    arrayListLibros = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lineas = leerArchivo("libros.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < lineas.size(); i++) {
        String libro[] = {"", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
        int c1 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~T");
        int c2 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~A");
        libro[0] = lineas.get(i).substring(c1 + 2, c2);
        int c3 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~A");
        int c4 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~E");
        libro[1] = lineas.get(i).substring(c3 + 2, c4);
        int c5 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~E");
        int c6 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~Tem");
        libro[2] = lineas.get(i).substring(c5 + 2, c6);
        int c7 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~Tem");
        int c8 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~Edi");
        libro[3] = lineas.get(i).substring(c7 + 4, c8);
        int c9 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~Edi");
        int c10 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~Anho");
        libro[4] = lineas.get(i).substring(c9 + 4, c10);
        int c11 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~Anho");
        int c12 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~I");
        libro[5] = lineas.get(i).substring(c11 + 5, c12);
        int c13 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~I");
        int c14 = lineas.get(i).indexOf("~End");
        libro[6] = lineas.get(i).substring(c13 + 2, c14);
        int z = i + 1;
        Libro temp = new Libro(libro[0], libro[1], libro[2], libro[3], libro[4], libro[5], libro[6], z);
        arrayListLibros.add(temp);
    }
}
```

So I don't know which is the problem because it was initialized before.

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is the line 19 of `SistemaDeGestion.java`?

Comment: The line 19 is

    public static int libros[][]= new int[arrayListLibros.size()][numeroMayor()];

Answer (score 5):

your `arrayListLibros` is not initialized i guess. static content is loaded when the class is loaded.

```
public static int libros[][]= new int[arrayListLibros.size()][numeroMayor()];
```

`arrayListLibros` is not initialized yet, thus leading to `NullPointerException` when calling size(), thus leading to `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

**FROM API:**

> Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static
>   initializer. An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that
>   an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the
>   initializer for a static variable.

### EDIT:

Simething like Below:

```
public class StaticTestForLaura {
    static List<String> arrayListLibros;
    static {
            arrayListLibros= new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListLibros.add("Laura");
    }
    public static int libros[]= new int[arrayListLibros.size()];

}
```

Comment: So, it has to be a non-static declaration or how can I initialize it depending on the size of this array?

Comment: Well but arrayListLibros wasn't empty.

Comment: @Laura can you post your whole code please, seems something fishy :)

Comment: @Laura  assuming `SistemaDeGestion sistema = new SistemaDeGestion();
` is inside main, this will not be evaluated while static content is loaded, you are initializing arraylistlibros in cardewatever method whihc is in `SistemaDeGestion` class.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like `arrayListLibros` has not been initialized at the point when `libros` is initialized.

Comment: It was initialized before     libros

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for data from your arrayListLibros without ever retrieving that data. Having a nullpointer exception probably means something isn't intialized yet (e.g. its value is null).

If you would debug this code, you'd see that the value of your arraylist was set to null. When this occurs, you should look for an initialization of your arraylist and initialize it if there isn't any. Another common mistake in my experience, is calling specific interaction with an object before it is initialized.

Comment: But I don't know because I've initialized the arrayList before initializing the matrix.